# Using Solace Binder with Spring Cloud Stream

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, solace

We are new to using Spring Cloud Stream with Solace Binders and we are doing a small POC.

The application publishes messages to 2 topics - **T_TENNIS_OUT** and **T_HOCKEY_OUT**.

We have a queue - **Q_GAME_DATA**,  that subscribes to both the topics T_TENNIS_OUT and T_HOCKEY_OUT.

We need to write a consumer to read message from the queue. 
The configuration for the solace binder used is below.

```
 spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        CHANNEL_GAME:
          destination: Q_GAME_DATA
          group: ????
          binder: local_solace
      binders:
        local_solace:
          type: solace
```

We are not clear and looking for answers on the below questions -

- What information from Solace configuration should we map to **group:** ??
- Do we need to having multiple  in bindings file like  CHANNEL_GAME1 and CHANNEL_GAME2 instead of only 1 channel CHANNEL_GAME?
- Do we also need to have topic names or topic subscription details in the binding file for the consumer?

Answer (score 0):

1. What information from Solace configuration should we map to group: ??

I assume that what you have done is you have already pre-provisioned the queue on the Solace Event Broker and have added the necessary topic subscriptions to it.

However, queue names will typically have the format of `{prefix}{destination}.{group}`. This is also mentioned in https://github.com/SolaceProducts/solace-spring-cloud/tree/master/solace-spring-cloud-starters/solace-spring-cloud-stream-starter under the "Solace Binder Configuration Options".

As such, please ensure that the name of the queue created on the Solace Event Broker follows the format of `{prefix}{destination}.{group}`. Once done, please map the respective portion of the queue name into the Solace configuration file accordingly. Also, as the queue has already been pre-provisioned on the Solace Event Broker, please set `provisionDurableQueue` to false in the Solace configuration file.

2. Do we need to having multiple in bindings file like CHANNEL_GAME1 and CHANNEL_GAME2 instead of only 1 channel CHANNEL_GAME?

Based on the explanation of your use case, there is no need to declare multiple channels in the Solace configuration file. You will still be able to have a consumer consume messages from the queue even with one channel.

3. Do we also need to have topic names or topic subscription details in the binding file for the consumer?

There won't be a need to add the topic subscription into the Solace configuration file if the necessary topic subscriptions have already been added to the pre-provisioned queue.

Also, there will be a need to set `provisionSubscriptionsToDurableQueue` to false in the Solace configuration file. If that is not done, then the value specified in `destination` in the Solace configuration file will be added as a topic subscription onto the queue.